# google static map API url is not working in android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, google-maps-static-api

We are using static google map url in our ionic application which is working fine in IOS and not working in android. We appended the API key along with the URL and the URL is working in desktop browser and on iOS device. But it is not working on android device and shown blank (white) space.
I have the following code below
home.scss

```
testmap-image {

  .mapcontainer {

position: relative;

img-loader {

  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;

  ion-spinner {
    height: 100px;
  }
}
  }
}
```

home.html

```
<div class="map-container">
  <img-loader *ngIf="getUrl"
              [src]="getUrl"
              width="100%"
              height="100px"
              backgroundSize="cover"
              backgroundPosition="center"  
              >
    </img-loader>
</div>
```

In the above code, I am getting correct URL from getUrl() method.

The URL is :
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=,22, market street, mumbai,India&zoom=15&size=650x150&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Can you please let me know what could be the issue and why it is not working on android device?

Regards

Comment: You can open a developer console from your desktop: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/ Maybe you'll find out what goes wrong that way

Comment: If I debug the app we are getting local cache url instead of google static map url. we are getting below code <img-loader backgroundposition="center" backgroundsize="cover" height="100px" width="100%" _nghost-c0="" style="display: block; height: 150px; width: 100%; background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image: url(&quot;file:///data/user/0/com.abc.test/cache/mapscache/302464373&quot;);">

    </img-loader> . Instead of google static map url, this (file:///data/user/0/com.abc.test/cache/mapscache/302464373&quot) getting passed. Can anybody have any idea about this?

Comment: Ah I see you're using cordova. 1. You should update the question with this information 2. Are there any errors in the browser log or logcat?